# Node.JS problem redirecting to new api endpoint after calling function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create an endpoint that updates a file using a post request, then redirects back to the home page. But the redirect isn't working.

However, when I comment out 'await sendMsg()', the redirect works fine.

Could you help me spot and fix the problem?

Thanks in advance!

```js
app.get('/add', async function(req, res){

    await sendMsg();
    res.redirect('/');

});

app.post('/update', async function(req, res){

    const {data} = req.body;

    async function writeData(data) {
        try { 
            return fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/config/' + 'task.json', JSON.stringify(data), 'utf8');
        }     
        catch (err) { 
            console.log('Problem writing to file.')
        }
    }

    await writeData(data);

});

async function sendMsg(){

    var pURL = 'http://localhost:6500/update';
    ...
    ...
    await fetch(pURL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({data:config})
    }) 
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

}
```

Comment: is it add or update ?

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect isn't working". did you get any error? put a console.log() before redirect to see if that is executed.

Comment: It won't redirect to the next page after function executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone!

I forgot to put res.end() at the end of the 'update' post API.

Thanks for the help.

The working code:

```js
app.get('/add', async function(req, res){

   try {
        await sendMsg();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
   }

   res.redirect('/');

});

app.post('/update', async function(req, res){

    const {data} = req.body;

    async function writeData(data) {
        try { 
            return fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/config/' + 'task.json', JSON.stringify(data), 'utf8');
        }     
        catch (err) { 
            console.log('Problem writing to file.')
        }
    }

    await writeData(data);

    res.end();

});

async function sendMsg(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
     var pURL = 'http://localhost:6500/update';
     ...
     ...
     fetch(pURL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({data:config})
     }) 
     .then(response => { // <---------- Little Change ----------
         resolve()
     })
     .catch(err => {
       console.log(err)
       reject()
      });

    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To await a function you need that function to return a promise. You need for sendMsg() to complete before you can redirect.

```
app.get('/add', async function(req, res){
   try{
    await sendMsg();
    res.redirect('/');
   }catch(e){
    //Error in sendMsg()
    console.log(e)
   }

});

async function sendMsg(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
     var pURL = 'http://localhost:6500/update';
     ...
     ...
     fetch(pURL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({data:config})
     }) 
     .then(response => { // <---------- Little Change ----------
         resolve()
     })
     .catch(err => {
       console.log(err)
       reject()
      });

    })

}
```

Comment: Very, very helpful, but still having the same issue

Comment: Do you see any error messages if so what does it say?

Comment: The sendMsg() function works fine. But I don't know how to correctly call it inside the 'add' endpoint.

Comment: No errors. The endpoint just keeps loading endlessly.

Comment: in the catch block in /add endpoint try adding res.end()

Comment: Same after adding 'res.end'. The sendMsg() post-request updates the file perfectly. However, when I comment out 'await sendMsg()', code redirects fine.

Comment: I made a little change. please try now.

Comment: Thanks! But issue persists.

Comment: It's probably your update api. It is updating the file but not sending the response back. So sendMsg() is still waiting for http://localhost:6500/update to reply back

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the code to include the 'update' API endpoint.